# Run OpenGL shader on part of a texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-es2

How do I run an OpenGL shader on just a portion of an off screen texture and leave the rest of the texture unmodified? Are there any calls that restrict the sampled pixels to just a rectangle or do I have to filter out the rectangle in the shader code?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds a bit like a problem you might be creating by using the wrong strategy when rendering to (or using the) render texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict rendering to just a rectangle by using either the viewport rect or the scissor rect.  These can be set by the [`glViewport`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) and [`glScissor`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml) calls, respectively.

The distinction is that setting the viewport will pretend that the viewport is the entire render target.  Any geometry you render will be scaled down to the viewport; the viewport will always extend from -1 to 1 in NDC (post-projective) coordinates.  The scissor rect, on the other hand, doesn't rescale any geometry or alter any coordinates - it simply suppresses rendering to any pixels outside the rect.